# Cloudmade Geocoding API country codes

Tags: geocoding, cloudmade

I'm coding an application that needs to geocode the centroid of ZIP codes. I'm using Cloudmade's geocoding API, but can't figure out what the country code for the United States is. All of their examples use Germany (http://cloudmade.com/documentation/geocoding).

I've tried all of the following, but the returned JSON says the search failed.

```
http://beta.geocoding.cloudmade.com/v3/{API KEY}/api/geo.location.search.2?format=json&source=OSM&enc=UTF-8&limit=1&q=[country=us][zip=44130]

http://beta.geocoding.cloudmade.com/v3/{API KEY}/api/geo.location.search.2?format=json&source=OSM&enc=UTF-8&limit=1&q=[country=usa][zip=44130]

http://beta.geocoding.cloudmade.com/v3/{API KEY}/api/geo.location.search.2?format=json&source=OSM&enc=UTF-8&limit=1&q=[country=unitedstates][zip=44130]
```

I can't use ZIP code alone, because often the results return something with a similar postal code from another country (Ukraine, for example). Does anyone know how to restrict such a search to the United States?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to geocode places in USA, please use the geocoding API v2:

http://cloudmade.com/misc/geocoding_v2.pdf

Comment: Thanks - just curious, do you know why geocoding in the USA isn't included in the more recent version?

Comment: @MasonDeCamillis, nope sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Cloudmade no longer offers a free geocoding/routing api...you must be a paying enterprise customer.

Comment: Yeah, if I pass just a 5-digit zip code, sometimes I get a US result, sometimes not. But all I have for input is zip codes, so that's not too reliable. Thanks though, good point about the difference between free style and structured search.